# in Marmalade 7.3 iOS status bar shows up even when UIStatusBarHidden is set

Tags: marmalade

Marmalade question

after upgrading to marmalade 7.3 from 7.0 i noticed that the status bar is showing up on my screen even though i have set "UIStatusBarHidden" to true.

Please note I do not want to use the statusbar EDK as I do not need to manipulate the status bar, instead hide it always.

I have not been using the EDK and it was working fine in earlier versions of Marmalade.
Any more settings added in Marmalade 7.3 or is it broken?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you want this to appear in your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

You can provide your own Info.plist in the Deploy Tool to accomplish this or in your MKB file you can add the following settings to your "deployments" section (at least in Marmalade 7.4.1):

```
iphone-show-status-bar='1'
iphone-uiviewcontroller-based-status-bar='0'
```

I think "iphone-show-status-bar" is backwards, because setting it to 1 actually sets the status bar to hidden instead of shown.  Also, initially the Deploy Tool will have "UIViewController based status bar appearance" unchecked, but despite this appearing "off", if it's missing from the MKB file then it will actually default to 1/true.  Once it's in the MKB file it should correspond with the visual appearance in the Deploy Tool.